# Why Ubuntu shows less HDD capacity?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a laptop with HDD 500GB and I installed Windows and Ubuntu on it. I used about 100gb for Windows partition and the rest is for Ubuntu (368gb). However when I load Ubuntu it shows 105gb volume, where's the rest.
I'm new to Ubuntu, I installed it yesterday so still getting the hang of it, but this I can not figure out so please help.

Here's a picture of "everything" for easier understanding:
[image]

Comment: What are you talking about?  "it" shows both volumes right there.

Comment: It does, but if you look in the right of the picture ("explorer") it shows 105gb volume so that confused me...I installed ubuntu on one partition, 368gb one so did not expect less gb to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest is "Computer" underneath your 105GB volume.
This is known your root filesystem, the "/" mount point - /dev/sda5  as shown in gparted.

Note there is some space allocated for a swap partition which is equivalent of the pagefile in windows.

Comment: Does that mean I can store more than 105gb of files on Ubuntu? I would like to use whole disk of course (368gb). Thanks

Comment: Yes, anything you store in your home directory (shown under places) will be in the 386gb partition.

Answer (score 2):

you have 105GB partition for windows. and 360G for ubuntu, you can access them from the Computer icon and you can store your data in the home folder.